# How do i create or edit basic, bmp image using risc-v assembler?

Tags: assembly, riscv, bmp

I am using rars, and i need to create empty bmp file, and edit it, but idk how.
I have code(attached below) that create file, but when i try to open exit file, it says that file is corrupted)

code:

```
.data
bmp_header: .byte 0x42, 0x4D, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
pixel_data: .byte 0x00

.text
main:
    
    la a0, filename
    li a1, 1
    li a7, 1024
    ecall

   
    mv s0, a0

    
    la a1, bmp_header
    li a2, 62
    mv a0, s0
    li a7, 64
    ecall

    
    la a1, pixel_data
    li a2, 1
    mv a0, s0
    li a7, 64
    ecall

   
    mv a0, s0
    li a7, 57
    ecall
```

Can you help me fix mine code, or give other one, and explain how it works, cause i am new in this, thanks

Comment: It's bad practice to just dump the header as a bunch of bytes. Write them out so you can see what each value is for. Also do not hardcode the length of the header, use labels. As is, you write 62 bytes but the header is actually 65. Furthermore the header says the file size is 62 as well, but of course you write an additional pixel byte.

Comment: And you will need a palette for a 1 bit indexed bmp.

Comment: You're looking for an algorithm and you want it coded in RISC V assembly.  Separate those issues (algorithm and assembly implementation).  Search about and develop your algorithm in a language you know well, test it to make sure it works, then translate that to assembly as literally as possible.  Then your assembly questions will be more like how do I do this loop or this if-then in assembly the same as I have in my high-level language.  Writing assembly code is so much easier when you already know what you want the program to do, and so much harder when you don't.

Comment: If you follow that approach, developing the algorithm you need for the program in a high level language like C or Java, test it to make sure it works, then the only bugs you'll have in assembly are translation errors, not algorithm design problems.  Debugging a broken algorithm in assembly is very hard especially when you don't know assembly very well.

Comment: @Jester There is any structure of bmp header? where i can find it to create it on my own?

Comment: See for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header)